# Flutter Firebase push notifications for iOS does not display

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I upgraded the flutter version of my app to the latest (1.22.5), since then push notifications are not displayed. I can see in the logs that the onMessage callback is being called and the notification data is being sent - testing via the firebase console on a real device - notification is not displayed

I upgraded to firebase messaging latest version and using ^7.0.3.
In the version before upgrading (flutter v1.17.0) when installing the build on device I do see the notifications.

I when over the install steps to try and see if anything was changed, but it seems that the configuration is ok.

output from fluter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G73 darwin-x64, locale en-IL)
    • Flutter version 1.22.5 at /Users/****/Desktop/Dev/tools/flutter
    • Framework revision 7891006299 (9 days ago), 2020-12-10 11:54:40 -0800
    • Engine revision ae90085a84
    • Dart version 2.10.4

 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/****/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.3, Build version 12C33
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 43.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2020.1.3)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin version 47.1.3
    • Dart plugin version 201.8538.45

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.3.2)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin version 43.0.3
    • Dart plugin version 193.6015.53

[✓] VS Code (version 1.52.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.16.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 arm (mobile) • emulator-5554                        • android-x86 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)
    • iPhone 12 (mobile)          • AEB05F91-087A-4EE1-8472-DB3DAD672C71 • ios         • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-3 (simulator)
```

EDIT:
BTW I tried to upload the app to test flight, the app was successfully uploaded but I got this warning from apple:

ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the 'aps-environment' entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the 'aps-environment' entitlement. Xcode does not automatically copy the aps-environment entitlement from provisioning profiles at build time. This behavior is intentional. To use this entitlement, either enable Push Notifications in the project editor's Capabilities pane, or manually add the entitlement to your entitlements file. For more information, see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW1.

I have the Capabilities enabled in Xcode so not sure whats the issue here

also got this in ios/Runner/Runner.entitlements

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

could the issue be related to this?

It seems like there is no real way to debug this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that there is a [bug filed on GitHub](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4437) about your issue. This should be addressed using the latest dev version as mentioned in [this comment](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4437#issuecomment-751626408) and [this PR](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/pull/4657):

> The latest dev version should be working fine but since you are having
> the same strange issue, I would recommend you take a look at the
> discussion in
> [#4097](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4097).